# Are there any Hidden Privileges (for non admins)

Tags: discussion, privileges

I was just wondering if there were any Hidden privileges for normal users that can be unlocked through reputation, badges, or any other measure.?

These could be either oversights in not putting these privileges in the faq, or on purpose as special easter eggs for members.

Comment: There is the edit trick that reveals deleted post at 500 rep. The meta post seems to have been deleted, though.

Comment: Edit trick? going to try this out on StackOverflow...

Comment: Not sure if it has been fixed, though... If it is then it would be recent.

Comment: E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102714/what-was-your-first-home-computer => http://stackoverflow.com/posts/102714/edit

Answer (score 10):

No, every privilege you can earn is documented in the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

<sup><sup>But if there were any, we wouldn't really talk about them, would we? Easter eggs are no fun once the secret is out.</sup></sup>

Comment: What can I offer you amongst some old wine, gold and nice meal.. ;) :P

Comment: So you're saying I should not talk about...well...the thing where....hmm, okay. He'll have to find those then.